# pretty printer for STL in lldb

Tags: python, stl, gdb, pretty-print, lldb

gdb 7 has some useful python script for STL structure http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Is there any similar tools for lldb? 
The information shown is pretty cryptic even with simple map or vector.

```
-> 100      h->moveReceivedSummaries(summaries);
   101      auto res = h->moveReceivedSummaries();
   102      EXPECT_TRUE(*summary == *res[1].get());
   103  }
(lldb) p summaries
(std::__1::map<int, std::__1::unique_ptr<ContextSummary, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> >, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, std::__1::unique_ptr<ContextSummary, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> > > > >) $0 = size=1 {
  (std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, std::__1::unique_ptr<ContextSummary, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> > >, void *>::value_type) [0] = {
    (int) first = 1
    (std::__1::unique_ptr<ContextSummary, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> >) second = {
      (std::__1::__compressed_pair<ContextSummary *, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> >) __ptr_ = {
        (std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<ContextSummary *, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> >) std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<ContextSummary *, std::__1::default_delete<ContextSummary> > = {
          (ContextSummary *) __first_ = 0x0000000100308390
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution could be just using Xcode when you are using Mac OS X.

[image]

In lldb, following([How can I get sensible variable displays when using libc++ in Xcode 4.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214477/how-can-i-get-sensible-variable-displays-when-using-libc-in-xcode-4-3-1)), I tried to use `command script import  ../libcxx.py` after downloading the python script from [this site](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/synthetic/libcxx.py).

However, the result is the same.

```
(lldb) p v
(std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > > >) $4 = size=0 {
  [0] = {
    __ptr_ = {
      std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<A *, std::__1::default_delete<A> > = {
        __first_ = 0x0000000100200000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The libcxx.py script does help me. However, it seems the link is no longer correct: it should be http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/synthetic/libcxx.py now.

Answer (score 2):

The initial focus for pretty-printers was more on the AppKit/UIKit types used for Mac/iOS app development, the C++ formatters are being added now.  For instance, Xcode 4.6.3:

```
(lldb) p string_map
(StringMapT) $0 = size=2 {
  (std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, void *>::value_type) [0] = {
    (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) first = "hi"
    (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) second = "there"
  }
  (std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, void *>::value_type) [1] = {
    (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) first = "this"
    (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) second = "that"
  }
}
```

Top of tree lldb:

```
(lldb) p string_map
(StringMapT) $0 = size=2 {
  [0] = {
    first = "hi"
    second = "there"
  }
  [1] = {
    first = "this"
    second = "that"
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that there are two C++ library versions in common use on Mac OS X today - the GNU libstdc++ library and the newer llvm libcxx library targetting C++11 (v. http://libcxx.llvm.org).  Different data formatters are needed for each of these two libraries.

lldb has a rich extension language for adding your own type formatters, either specifying which existing elements to print or calling out to Python to format a type for printing.  The goal is to have the common C++/Objective-C types handled by built in formatters but you're not limited to those provided by lldb if you're willing to write your own.  See http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html for more information.